# List Manipulation on Array with subscript elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to write a function which operates on an array with subscripted elements.

As an example i have the array a={$1_3$,$2_2$,$4_1$}, which means i have 3 amounts of value 1, 2 amounts of value 2 and 1 amount of value 4. If the subscripted amount reaches 0, then the element has to be dropped from the array.

Now i need a function

```
edit[a_,lower_,raise_]:=...
```

with lower_ being an array of elements which shall be decreased by 1 and raise_ being the array of elements which should be increased by 1. These two arrays have to contain the value and not the position of the element which should be changed.

So if i would call the function with

```
edit[{Subscript[1, 3], Subscript[2, 2], Subscript[4, 1]}, {1, 1, 4}, {2, 5}]
```

the output should be

```
{Subscript[1, 1],Subscript[2, 3], Subscript[5, 1]}
```

because

- the value 1 has to be decreased 2 times, leaving it with the amount 1
- the value 4 has to be decreased once, thus the amount reaches 0 and it has to be dropped
- the value 2 has to be increased once, increasing the amount to a total of 3
- the value 5 has to be increased once, and since its not in the list yet, it has to be added

I want to use subscript because it makes it easy to read and seems to behave like a normal 2 dimensional array, but i am open to good alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with "classic" functions `Tally` and `GatherBy`

```
edit[a_, lower_, raise_] := 
 DeleteCases[#, _[_, 0]] &[
  Subscript[#[[1, 1]], Total@#[[All, 2]]] & /@ GatherBy[#, First] &@
   Join[a, Subscript @@@ (-Tally[-lower]), Subscript @@@ Tally@raise]]

edit[{Subscript[1, 3], Subscript[2, 2], Subscript[4, 1]}, {1, 1, 4}, {2, 5}]
(* {Subscript[1, 1], Subscript[2, 3], Subscript[5, 1]} *)
```

Comment: @RunnyKine I thought that it is invalid input. Anyway, one can add `c_ /; c <= 0` instead of `0` in `DeleteCases`.

Comment: You're probably right that it's invalid input. +1

Comment: all 3 answers were pretty good, thanks a lot

Comment: @ybeltukov Is it possible to return an empty array when invalid input is made? Invalid Input would also be raising a value lower then 1.
ex: `edit[{Subscript[1, 1], Subscript[3, 1]},{1,1,2},{0}]`

Answer (score 8):

Here is an approach using `Association` for **Version 10+**.

```
edit[a_, lower_, raise_] := Subscript @@@ Normal@DeleteCases[#, 0] &@
         Merge[{#, #2, #3}, Total] &[<|Rule @@@ a|>, -Counts[lower], Counts[raise]]
```

Use:

```
edit[{Subscript[1, 3], Subscript[2, 2], Subscript[4, 1]}, {1, 1, 4}, {2, 5}]
```

> $\left\{1_1,2_3,5_1\right\}$

Comment: Is Association already implemented in Mathematica 8.0? Or which Version do i need to run it?

Comment: @kon. This is for Version 10 and above. Sorry, I didn't know you were on Version 8.

Comment: Actually its my fault for not mentioning it, but unfortunately i cant use it and i dont think i can convince my university to upgrade to version 10 for me.

Comment: @kon. You can download a trial version which is free for 30 days and try it out or use the Wolfram programming cloud.

Comment: Very nice code!  I also thought to use associations but my code is not nearly as good. (I forgot entirely about `Counts` for one thing.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. I rewrote the code after asking myself "How would Mr. Wizard approach this?" :)

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = {Subscript[1, 3], Subscript[2, 2], Subscript[4, 1]};
```

> $\left\{1_3,2_2,4_1\right\}$

```
ClearAll[foo, editFX];
foo = Flatten[GatherBy[Join[#1, Subscript @@@ Tally[#2] ], First] /.
     {Subscript[x_, a_], Subscript[x_, b_]} :>
                  (Subscript[x, a + #3 b] /. Subscript[_, 0] :> Sequence[])] &;
editFX[lst_, arg1 : {___}, arg2 : {___}] := With[{t = foo[lst, arg1, -1]}, foo[t, arg2, 1]];

editFX[lst, {1, 1, 4}, {2, 5}]
```

> $\left\{1_1,2_3,5_1\right\}$

Or

```
ClearAll[editFX2];
editFX2 = Fold[foo[#1, First@#2, Last@#2] &, #, {{#2, -1}, {#3, 1}}] &;
editFX2[lst, {1, 1, 4}, {2, 5}]
```

> $\left\{1_1,2_3,5_1\right\}$

Comment: Nice. I like it. +1

Comment: Thank you @RunnyKine.